# The display background color is not changed after a call to `fill` in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm following an example in a pygame tutorial:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

surf = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 450))
#surf.fill((255, 0, 0))
surf.fill(pygame.Color(255, 0, 0))
pygame.display.update()
input()
```

As you can see, I've tried two ways:

1. surf.fill((255, 0, 0))
2. surf.fill(pygame.Color(255, 0, 0))

Neither works for me.

My working environment is macOS, the version of pygame is 1.9.6, the version of Python is 3.8.

What I saw:

[image: The background is not red]

Why is the background color not changed?

Comment: what's your python version ? No problem exists for Python 3.6.2 in which I saw the red background. Btw, pygame version is the same with yours.

Comment: Try `pygame.event.poll()` before `input()`.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Python 3.8.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Still the same. The only difference is that the cursor becomes the "loading" cursor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After searching for "pygame fill doesn't work" for a while and trying each one of the suggested answers, I found out that the only way to make the background color change happen is to upgrade `pygame` to `2.0.0.dev4`.

Since by default `pip` only installs the most recent stable version of a package, I need to specify the version explicitly like `pip install pygame==2.0.0.dev4`.

And now I can see the red background.

Comment: Thank you! Just wasted so much time trying to figure out why this wasn't working.

Answer (score 3):

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
surf = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 450))
run = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    #surf.fill((255, 0, 0))
    surf.fill(pygame.Color(255, 0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: 1) First we intialize our pygame using pygame.init() function , 2)We define width and height of our game using pygame.display.set_mode((width,  height)), 3) We use run variable which indicate that our game is running 4) pygame.time.Clock we create an object to track the time, 5) clock.ticks() refresh rate of frame we use 60 which means 60 frame in 1 second, 6)then we create object to capture the event like keys, mouse etc 7) you cannot directly close the window by clicking on close button we define function on the close button if event.type == pygame.QUIT stop running the pygame.window

Comment: 8) surf.fill() to fill the screen with any color 9) And the most important  pygame.display.update() to portion of your screen

Comment: @SartajAnsari Please edit your answer and explain why the code in the example didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem recently. I am using MacOS 10.15.7 and tried versions from 2.0.0 through 2.0.3dev4 of Pygame installed via Pip. Nothing worked. Until I read the following text in the Pygame documentation (https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/color.html):

> Color objects support equality comparison with other color objects and
> 3 or 4 element tuples of integers. There was a bug in pygame 1.8.1
> where the default alpha was 0, not 255 like previously.

So, defining the RGB color with a 4 elements tuple (last number the alpha value, 255 opaque) solved the problem.